# Angular 7 : Download pdf file under app folder

Tags: angular7

I am trying to download pdf file under my project folder (\src\app\files\pdf\iBATIS.pdf) when clicking the button. When clicking button, [Failed- no file] is shown and no file is downloaded. What do I need to do to be able to download this file? Could you please help me.

When I moved the pdf file under (\src\assets) folder, the pdf file is successfully downloaded. Why the file cannot be downloaded under (\src\app\files\pdf\iBATIS.pdf)?

```
    html

        button type="button" (click)="downloadPDF()" => Click button

    ts ( ts file path is src\app\pdfdownload\pdfdownload.component.ts)
        downloadPDF(){
            let link=document.createElement("a");
            link.download="ibatis.pdf";
            link.href="../files/pdf/iBATIS.pdf"; 
            link.click();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

***, First of all, *** according to my knowledge, `asset` folder in the project is given to access data and download stuff.

If the file is already on the server, then you can try these following ways to download:

```
f1() {
    window.open('path', '_blank');
}
```

or:

```
f1() {
   window.open('/assets/files/blabla.pdf', '_blank');
}
```

or:

```
<a download="filename" target="_blank" href="/assets/files/blabla.pdf">
  Click here to download image
</a>
```

and if you want to do this in angular then I think you should try `$http` method of angular like following

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
     anchor.attr({
         href: 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(data),
         target: '_blank',
         download: 'filename.csv'
     })[0].click();

  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // handle error
  });
```

might this work for you!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I move my pdf file under assets folder and  use f1().  It works fine.